# Create table with reorder-able rows in Angular 8 Component without using any package, Angular material, cdk, primeng or jQuery

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, reorderable-list

I want to create a table in Angular Component where I can show all the data coming from Database in a tabular form and as per the requirement of user he/she should be able to rearrange any of the rows showed in table

I want to implement this without using any package, Angular material, cdk, primeng or jQuery

Is there any implementation with Javascript or typescript?

Comment: You can actually check the Angular CDK code, and reverse it, though it will take you time to understand. and also it's simple to display data coming from DB using <table> tag and for sorting, filtering you can use RXJS with BehaviorSubject.

Comment: Is there any implementation available for this?